# tikzcalendar days name and anchors

Tags: pdftex, tikz-calendar

I'm using `tikzcalendar` and I'd like to:

1. insert name of days on top (maybe abbreviated Mon, Tue, Wed, and so on)
2. **automatically** insert dashed vertical lines to separate the weekend days.

In the following MWE I had some progress on (2), but it is not good since I have to inform when the **first Friday** of calendar occurs and use that node as reference.

When date changes, I have to edit the code again.

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar,calc}

\begin{document}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  every day/.style={anchor=mid,opacity=1,minimum width=2.5ex},%
  every node/.style={inner sep=2pt,rectangle}%
]
\calendar (cal) [dates=2018-06-01 to 2018-12-10,
  month list,%
  month label left,%
  month text=\textcolor{black}{\%mt},%
  month yshift=1.7em,%
  day xshift=3.5ex,%
  ]
  if (Sunday) [every day/.append style={font=\slshape},red]
  ;
  %%
  %% we need to use 1st Friday node to compute the (up) node
  %%
  \node (up) at ($(cal-2018-06-01.north east)!.5!(cal-2018-06-02.north west)$ ) {};
  %%
  %% we need to use last month 1st Friday node to compute the (down) node
  %%
  \node (down) at (%
   %% repeat (up) node
   {$(cal-2018-06-01.north east)!.5!(cal-2018-06-02.north west)$}%
   |-%
   {$(cal-2018-12-01.south east)!.5!(cal-2018-12-02.south west)$}%
   ) {};
  %%
  %% dashed lines from (up) to (down)
  %%
  \foreach \i in {0,...,4}{% <-- the number could change
  \draw[dashed]%
    ([xshift=3.5*7*\i ex]up.center)--([xshift=3.5*7*\i ex]down.center)
    ([xshift=3.5*7*\i ex + 7ex]up.center)--([xshift=3.5*7*\i ex + 7ex]down.center)
  ;
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Adaptations:**

- added parameters `\dateFrom`, `\dateTo`, `\xDist`
- added function `\dayOfWeek`, which does a modulo calculation and selects the day of the week
- used new parameters everywhere
- define `coordinate` for `(up)` and `(down)`

**Comment:**

Because the week starts always with a monday and there is even left space if there is no monday at the begin of any selected month, there is the magic number `4.5` for getting the x-position of the first friday. If you start with another day this value must be changed.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar,calc}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp

\newcommand{\dayOfWeek}[1]{%
    % give back day of week (here in german)
    % calc #1 modulo 7
    \FPeval{\result}{trunc(#1-(7*trunc(#1/7,0)),0)}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\result}{0}}{
        Mo
    }{\ifthenelse{\equal{\result}{1}}{
        Di
    }{\ifthenelse{\equal{\result}{2}}{
        Mi
    }{\ifthenelse{\equal{\result}{3}}{
        Do
    }{\ifthenelse{\equal{\result}{4}}{
        Fr
    }{\ifthenelse{\equal{\result}{5}}{
        Sa
    }{\ifthenelse{\equal{\result}{6}}{
        So
    }{}}}}}}}
}

% Parameters %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\dateFrom}{2018-06-01}
\newcommand{\dateTo}{2018-12-10}
\newcommand{\xDist}{3.5ex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    every day/.style={anchor=mid,opacity=1,minimum width=2.5ex},%
    every node/.style={inner sep=2pt,rectangle}%
]

    \calendar (cal) [
        dates=\dateFrom to \dateTo,
        month list,%
        month label left,%
        month text=\textcolor{black}{\%mt},%
        month yshift=1.7em,%
        day xshift=\xDist,%
    ]
    if (Sunday) [every day/.append style={font=\slshape},red];

    % Friday is on a fix position (4), because week starts always with monday.
    % Therefore 4.5 for line between friday and saturday.
    \coordinate (up) at (4.5*\xDist,0 |- cal-\dateFrom.north);
    \coordinate (down) at (4.5*\xDist,0 |- cal-\dateTo.south);

    % dashed lines from (up) to (down)
    \foreach \i in {0,...,4}{% <-- the number could change
    \draw[dashed]%
        ([xshift=7*\i*\xDist]up.center)--([xshift=7*\i*\xDist]down.center)
        ([xshift=7*\i*\xDist + 2*\xDist]up.center)--([xshift=7*\i*\xDist + 2*\xDist]down.center);
    }

    % write day of week above:  A month starting with sunday (day 6) and
    % having 31 days would have the maximum x-position 6+31=37.
    % Therefore the range goes from 0 to 36.
    \foreach \i in {0,...,36}{
        \node[] at (\i*\xDist,0 |- cal-\dateFrom.north) [above=2mm]{\dayOfWeek{\i}};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort. So, the range for `\foreach` (in your example, `0,...,36`) should be changed manually? From where comes the mysterious value `36`?

Comment: I tested a lot and it seems that it is automatically adapted.

Comment: 36 is the maximum of a month starting with sunday (day 6) and having 31 days: 6+31=37. Because for starts with 0 it is 36. Yes, it has to be adapted manually at the moment.

Comment: But I think it is perfect since all cals I use have Mon as 1st day.

Comment: In most cases, if you have multiple months nothing has to be changed. Only if you have for example just months from 2018-10-01 to 2018-11-30, you could change the `36` to `32`. To automate that, one could iterate over the last day of each month and look at the maximum x-position.

Comment: It would be good, but I'm afraid the iteration could not be easy. Thanks again.